# Windows 8 x64 & NDK r8e & C++ breakpoint in Eclipse, is it possible?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

Is it possible to setup Android NDK development environment on Windows 8 x64, and supports break point in C++ code?
If yes, is there a guide?
Thanks.